# Java writer only writing last element of arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

Here is my problem, I have an arraylist of objects which I wish to write to a a text file. For the most part this works but rather annoyingly it only writes the last element of the arraylist. My code is as follows:

```
public void write() throws IOException {
    try {
        File file = new File("C:\\contacts.txt");   
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        for(contacts contact:contactList) {
            StringBuffer contactrec=new StringBuffer();
            contactrec.append(contacts.getID());
            contactrec.append(",");
            contactrec.append(contacts.getName());
            contactrec.append(",");
            contactrec.append(contacts.getNotes());
            bw.write(contactrec.toString());
            bw.newLine();
            System.out.println("Contacts have been updated");
        }

        bw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If the arraylist was say the size of 3 the writer would write the last element of the arraylist 3 times to the file. So if the last element was :
"12,John Doe,fish" the text file would have:

```
 12,John Doe,fish
 12,John Doe,fish
 12,John Doe,fish
```

written in it. I want to know how to fix and why it happens, any help is appreciated thanks in advance.

My contacts class is this and is populated with objects read from a csv file:

```
public class contacts {
    private static String ID;
    private static String Name;
    private static String Notes;

    public contacts(String ID, String Name, String Notes){
        this.ID = ID;
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Notes = Notes;
    }

    public static String getID(){
        return ID;
    }

    public static String getName(){
        return Name;
    }

    public static String getNotes(){
        return Notes;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return("ID = " + this.getID() + " " + "Name = " + this.getName()+ " " +     "Notes = " + this.getNotes()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: How is `contactList` populated?  Please include that code and the code for the `contacts` class.

Comment: Can you check the line `for(contacts contact:contactList)`?  shouldnot you use `contact` instead of `contacts` in the body of the `for`-loop?

Comment: Please remove all the static modifiers from the `contacts` class

Comment: I just changed the contact to contacts(name of object class), in the for loop but still the problem remains prevalent.

Comment: I have removed all static references in the contacts class but now there is a index out of bounds error

Answer (score 2):

You are using static methods , so everything is related to the `contacts` class and not the object `contact`.

So change the data accessor methods to non static. Populate the objects correctly and then in the for loop instead of using `contacts` use `contact`.

Comment: The OP needs to change all member variables to non-static as well.

Comment: I am now getting an index out of bounds error:1

Comment: Put your updated code.

Comment: Change these to `contactrec.append(contact.getID());`